# Does light return to its starting point in a closed universe?

Tags: universe, radiation, boundary-conditions, stars

I was reading about the possibility that our universe could be a closed sphere.

from Sean Carroll “in a closed universe, one that wraps around on itself to form a compact geometry, like a three dimensional sphere ... cancels the positive energy from everything else. A closed universe has exactly zero energy”

There are many online articles about this (such as the one I mentioned in the comments below) - they all seem to date from around Nov 2019 (so someone must have proposed something new at that time)

I wondered how that would affect stars close to that ‘boundary’ ..

Would their radiation curve along it in a loop?

Comment: What boundary are you talking about? Please give a reference to what you read. Most likely either it is wrong or you misunderstood it.

Comment: Could you add the source you were reading in?

Comment: Planck evidence for a closed Universe and a possible crisis for cosmology

Eleonora Di Valentino, Alessandro Melchiorri & Joseph Silk

Comment: Also - from Sean Carroll “in a closed universe, one that wraps around on itself to form a compact geometry, like a three dimensional sphere ... cancels the positive energy from everything else. A closed universe has exactly zero energy”

Comment: @G.Smith - is the outer circumference of a closed sphere not regarded as a boundary in this case?

Comment: @Wookie What "outer circumference" are you talking about? Think about a lower-dimensional example of a closed surface: if you're walking on a sphere, how do you get to the edge?

Comment: @AlmostClueless - I added some of what I read. Do you see why my question arises now?

Comment: @probably_someone - if I’m standing on a sphere and I see a star inside it under my feet does it not have to cross a boundary to touch my feet?

Comment: Wookie, a normal 3D ball, eg a billiard ball, has a 2D curved surface, with no boundaries. That 2D surface is what mathematicians mean by a sphere. When discussing higher dimensions, we  call that surface a 2-sphere. The "surface" of a 4D ball is called a 3-sphere. It also has no boundaries, and that's the kind of structure Sean Carroll is talking about.

Comment: I guess what I’m reading just makes it sound like there’s a ‘ball of universe’ rather than an ‘infinity of universe.’ If the universe is finite starlight will be contained.

Comment: @PM2Ring - thank you, that is helpful

Comment: @Wookie In this example, there is no such thing as "under it". Your vision and movement are both confined to the sphere.

Comment: @PM2Ring -re what you were saying on Jul. 13, is it that the 4D ball, or 3-sphere, includes time and consequently (as per Heisenberg's UP) can't be known to include any energy?  (That would make sense of Sean Carroll's remark as cited by the OP, as well as implying that "higher" dimensions are outward from an object, if that object is spherical:  However, I've never heard of any reference being made to "lower" dimensions, even in the numerous discussions of black holes, so I'd usually taken "higher" dimensions to be hypothetical ones lacking empirical evidence.) Might you suggest a reference?

Comment: @Edouard It does not include time. I was talking about the possibility of space (not spacetime) being a 3-sphere. That's the simplest 3D space with positive global curvature. It's the simplest because its curvature is constant, just like the curvature of a 2-sphere. Note that *if* space is a 3-sphere that doesn't necessarily imply that there's some physical 4D ball that it's the surface of. Sorry, I don't understand the rest of your question, especially the part about higher dimensions being outward from an object.

Comment: The clarification by PM 2Ring was extremely useful, short-circuiting some lunatic fringe ideas I might've otherwise run away with.  My orientation toward modern languages had somehow left me with a notion that "higher" meant "further from the earth's center", which it may have, but only in the origin of the term, back when the earth was considered to be either flat or hemispherical.  I'm not only dependent on PSE, but addicted to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I see the misunderstanding.  You are thinking of a [ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)), not a [sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere).

The closed 3-ball is the set of points $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2$, like a basketball.  The 2-sphere is the set of points $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$, like the *surface* of a basketball.

A closed $n$-ball is compact and has a boundary, namely the $(n-1)$-sphere.  The $n$-sphere, on the other hand, is compact but does **not** have a boundary.  An ant walking on the surface of a basketball could travel forever in any direction and would never encounter a line it could not cross.

Comment: Thank you J. Murray. In reference to my question though when starlight reaches the ‘surface’ does it then travel as an ant would across the basketball?

Comment: @Wookie A 3D ball has a 2D surface, a 4D ball has a 3D surface. The starlighr is always in that surface, there's nowhere else to go. And if the starlight travels long enough in a straight line, it gets back to where it started from, just like an ant on a basketball.

Comment: @Wookie As PM 2Ring says, you never *reach* the surface, because you are always *on* it.  A 3-sphere is impossible (at least for me) to visualize, because it can only be embedded in 4D space.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thank you very much.